# Coordinate conversion in c++

Tags: c++, coordinates, coordinate-transformation, polar-coordinates

I am trying to convert different coordinate systems. From polar to rectangular and vice versa. My `pol_to_rect()`function is not working properly. It is giving very small values(~10^(-44)) after converting and also before converting. There might be some problem while using the sin() and cos() functions. The `rect_to_pol()` is working fine for positive values. 
Edit - When I changed `atan()` to `atan2()` how can I incorporate other values of x and y.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
#define PI 3.1415926
class Polar; // Forward declaration

class Rectangular {
    private:
        float x, y;

    public:
        Rectangular() {} // default constructor
        Rectangular(float mv_x, float mv_y) {
            x = mv_x;
            y = mv_y;
        }

        void showData() const;
        Polar rect_to_pol();
        float& get_x() {
            return x;
        }

        float& get_y() {
            return y;
        }

};

void Rectangular::showData() const {
    cout << "--Rectangular--" << endl;
    cout << "x: " << x << "\t" <<"y: " << y << endl;
}




class Polar {
    private:
        float r;
        float theta;
    public:
        Polar() {} // default constructor
        Polar(float mv_r, float mv_theta) {
            r = mv_r;
            theta = mv_theta;
        }
        void showData();
        Rectangular pol_to_rect();
        float& get_r(){
            return r;
        }
        float& get_theta() {
            return theta;
        }

};

void Polar::showData() {
    cout << "--Polar--" << endl;
    cout << "r:" << r << "\t" << "Theta(Radians):" << theta << endl;
}

Rectangular Polar::pol_to_rect() {
    Rectangular temp;
    temp.get_x() = r * cos(theta*(PI/180.0)); // in degrees
    temp.get_y() = r * sin(theta*(PI/180.0));
    return temp;

}

Polar Rectangular::rect_to_pol() {
    Polar temp;

    temp.get_r() = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
    temp.get_theta() = atan2(y, x);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    Rectangular r1(-1, -1), r2;
    Polar p1(12.0, 30.0), p2;
    r1.showData();
    p2 = r1.rect_to_pol();
    cout << "After Conversion (RECT TO POLAR)->" << endl;
    p2.showData();

    p1.showData();
    r2 = p1.pol_to_rect();
    cout << "After Conversion (POLAR TO RECT)" << endl;
    r2.showData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable shadowing in `Polar(float r, float theta) { r = r; theta = theta; }` `r = r` is a self assignment of the parameter, leaving the member `r` unchanged. Use Member initializer list: `Polar(float r, float theta): r(r), theta(theta) { }`

Comment: Are you aware of `atan2()`? I am quite surprised that you describe `rect_to_pol()` as working fine.

Comment: @Yunnosch no I am not aware of that. I checked with an online tool which matched with my value.. what is the problem?

Comment: Try coordinates from all four quadrants (x>0, y>0; x<0, y>0; x<0, y<0 and x>0, y<0) and check whether you still like the results. Note that your function might be suitable for your usecase, but it is restricted to only a subset of possible inputs.

Comment: That I know.. My bad I should have mentioned it.. I am trying for positive values only

Comment: A, I see. That is what I meant by "subset". Yes, now I understand. May I recommend to nevertheless move to atan2(), just to form the habit and prevent unpleasant surprises if ever you want to reuse this code? It was my mistake not to mention that my comment is probably unrelated to the problem you are asking about.

Comment: The program is working fine after using a member initializer list.

Comment: @Yunnosch of course. Thanks. I was just searching about atan2(). I'll edit it.

Comment: I understand the other comments that the problem is around `r=r;` where you seem to mean two different but identically named `r`s. I recommend to form another habit and use longer, more explicit identifiers. Even if `r` is obvious for a radius, I wouldn't trust myself with reliably keeping track of which `r` is meant where. E.g. I tend to use a naming pattern for parameters of constructors which are used to init member variables (`mv`) like `mvInit` and then do `...:mv(mvInit){...`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I am finding difficulty incorporating different quadrants using atan2(). Please help @Yunnosch

Comment: Not related to your question, but a getter that returns a non-const reference is *worse* than a straight plain public data member. Don't do that. And before you ask, a getter/setter pair is not much better.

Comment: Rect_to_pol returns an angle in radians, pol_to_rect assumes the angle is in degrees. This is inconsistent. Also PI should have a few more digits.

Comment: @n.m. what could I do without using the getter references?

Comment: @kvantour but I am converting it in the respective functions.

Comment: A pair of coordinates should be immutable. You construct it from two numbers, and it stays unchanged until it dies. If you need a new pair of coordinates, construct a new one. A simple implementation would be: `struct Rectangular { const float x, y; Rectangular(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}; /* other methods */ };`